# Button and Anchor actions performed when clicking below them while in inspect mode

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

https://codepen.io/joshleewillis/full/MWZboPm

I have linked my project above. The button and tweet link perform as expected on browser and mobile formats. However, once in inspect mode at a media query below 600px screen width, they behave unexpectedly. If you hover just below the button, it highlights with the option to inspect. And if you click this region, the button performs its action. Likewise, if you hover over the button to inspect it, the tweet link highlights, and it is directly above the button. You will see the code if you click the link, but here is what I have for those elements:

```
<a id="tweet-quote" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_top">
    <img id="twitter-logo" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/67-670821_twitter-logo-outline-transparent-twitter-logo-white.png" class="clickable links-buttons color-scheme">
</a>

<button id="new-quote" onclick="getQuote()" class="links-buttons clickable color-scheme">
    <b>New  Quote</b>
</button>
```

```
#new-quote {
    float: right;
    padding: 1.25%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
#tweet-quote {
    text-align: left;
  }
#twitter-logo {
    height: auto;
    width: 4.5%;
    padding: 1%;
  }
.clickable:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
.links-buttons {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #tweet-quote {
    flex-basis: 10%;
  }
    #new-quote {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
.links-buttons {
    top: 0;
  }
#twitter-logo {
    padding: 4%;
  }
#new-quote {
    padding: 2%;
    min-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

It should be noted that the container in which both the anchor and button are located switches to flexbox at 600px or below. The issue is that when in inspect mode at this screen size, pressing the "new quote" button performs the action that clicking the tweet link should. I have only been able to replicate this bug while in inspect mode. While checking on my personal mobile phone, the button and link behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Less than 600px, the `#quote-box`'s `flex-direction` is set to `column`. Since everything is a child of that `div`, it stacks them up vertically.

If you want them to align horizontally, nest the `#tweet-quote` and `#new-quote` elements in a container div. Something along the lines of...

```html
<div id="quote-box">
 <!-- other elements -->
  <div id="button-container">
    <a id="tweet-quote" ...></a>
    <button id="new-quote">...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#button-container {
  display: flex;
  // default flex-direction is row but you can be explicit
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```